# Redirect stopping multiple file upload CodeIgniter 3.0.4

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to use redirect on my filemanager controller on my upload function when the form is success full.

How ever when I have the `redirect('filemanager')` on my success part of form it stops multiple files from being uploaded and then only uploads one.

> But when I comment it out like so `// redirect('filemanager')` I can
>   upload multiple images fine.

**Question:** How can I still use my redirect on success form but make sure it uploads the multiple images that is selected rather than just one.

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Filemanager extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('upload');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'File Manager';

        $data['template'] = 'template/common/filemanager_view';
        $this->load->view('template/common/template_view', $data);
    }

    public function upload() {

        $files = $_FILES;

        if ($files) {

            $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++) {           

                $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];  

                $url = '';

                $directory = $this->input->get('directory');

                if (isset($directory)) {
                    $url .= $directory . '/';
                } else {
                    $url .= '';
                }  

                $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'images/catalog/' . $url;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = 5000;
                $config['max_width'] = 0;
                $config['max_height'] = 0;
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

                    // reminder todo some error code here

                } else {

                    redirect('filemanager');

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you placed redirect inside for loop thats why it stops your multiple upload. Whenever your method get error it will redirect and for loop won't completed.

Comment: @Vinie what would you suggest to do?

Comment: If error occur save error message in array or any other way and put redirection outside for loop

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working now thanks to [@Vinie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3247517/vinie) suggestion

```
<?php

class Filemanager extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('upload');
    }

    public function index($results = NULL) {
        $data['title'] = 'File Manager';

        $data['upload_data'] = array();

        if ($results) {
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $data['upload_data'][] = array(
                    'file_name' => $result['file_name']
                );
            }
        }

        $upload_errors = $this->upload->display_errors();

        if (isset($upload_errors)) {
            $data['upload_errors'] = $upload_errors;
        } else {
            $data['upload_errors'] = '';
        }

        $data['template'] = 'template/common/upload_view';
        $this->load->view('template/common/template_view', $data);
    }

    public function upload() {

        $files = $_FILES;

        if ($files) {

            $check_if_any_error = 0;

            $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++) {           

                $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];  

                $url = '';

                $directory = $this->input->get('directory');

                if (isset($directory)) {
                    $url .= $directory . '/';
                } else {
                    $url .= '';
                }  

                $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'images/catalog/' . $url;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = 5000;
                $config['max_width'] = 0;
                $config['max_height'] = 0;
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

                    $check_if_any_error++;

                } else {

                    $results[] = $this->upload->data();
                }


            }

            if($check_if_any_error > 0 ) {

                $this->index();

            } else {

                $this->index($results);

            }

        } else {

            redirect('filemanager');

        }
    }
}
```